# Questions about right value reference in C++

Tags: c++, reference

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void swap(int& a, int& b) 
{

    cout << "address of a: " << &a << " value of a: " << a << endl;
    cout << "address of b: " << &b << " value of b: " << b << endl;

    int tmp{move(a)};

    cout << "address of tmp: " << &tmp << " value of tmp: " << tmp << endl;

    a = move(b);
    b = move(tmp);

    cout << "address of a: " << &a << " value of a: " << a << endl;
    cout << "address of b: " << &b << " value of b: " << b << endl;
    
}

void swap_no_move(int& a, int& b)
{

    cout << "address of a: " << &a << " value of a: " << a << endl;
    cout << "address of b: " << &b << " value of b: " << b << endl;

    int tmp{ a };

    cout << "address of tmp: " << &tmp << " value of tmp: " << tmp << endl;

    a = b;
    b = tmp;

    cout << "address of a: " << &a << " value of a: " << a << endl;
    cout << "address of b: " << &b << " value of b: " << b << endl;

}

int main() {
    
    int a = 10;
    int b = 5;

    swap(a, b);

    cout << endl;

    int c = 10;
    int d = 5;

    swap_no_move(c, d);

    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

[image]

I have two swap functions: swap and swap_no_move. According to what I read from the book, there should be no "copy" in function swap which means the address of tmp should be the same for tmp and an in function swap. However, the output I got shows there is no difference between these two functions, did I do something wrong?

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Please [edit] your question and copy-paste the output as text.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you've expected to happen. `std::move` doesn't actually move anything. In fact it's only a cast. For primitive values there will always copying involved.

Answer (score 2):

The definition

```
int tmp{move(a)};
```

doesn't move the reference or the variable `a` itself. It creates a brand new variable `tmp` which the compiler allocates space for. Then the *value* of `a` is moved into `tmp`.

And since moving `int` values can't really be done, it's exactly the same as

```
int tmp = a;
```

Comment: "And since moving int values can't really be done" might be clearer as "since `int` doesn't _contain_ any pointers". This isn't _entirely_ accurate, but it helps new users understand the concept.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I am still confused about right value reference. From my understanding through right reference the "copy" action can be skipped which means there is no need to allocate space in memory, is it possible? If so, would you like to give me some examples?

Comment: @will_xdxd If you define a variable that is *not* a reference (like `tmp` in both your functions), then it's a distinct variable which needs separate space allocated for it. There's no way to initialize it so it shares memory with any other variable.